# how to create arrays with prepare statment and while loop?

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I am trying to create an update page couldnt list items 
here is that question
[Cant list item values in inputs in update page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845306/cant-list-items-when-updating-with-prepare-statments)

My question is how to create array with while and use it in inputs ?

here what I am trying to do, not sure if I am doing right

```
<?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = ? AND user_id = ?";
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $param_item_id, $param_user_id);
            $param_item_id = $item_id;
            $param_user_id = $user_id;
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                if($result->num_rows == 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          $ids[] = $row['item_id'];
                          $names[] = $row['item_name'];
                          $titles[] = $row['item_title'];
                          $images[] = $row['item_image'];
                    } else {
                        echo "no items found";
                      }
                }
            }
        }   
?>

I want to get values from table with the query and use them in inputs 


         <input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $names; ?>">        
<input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item_titles; ?>">
         <input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $images; ?>">
```

Comment: you want to put all the names in one textbox?

Comment: yes, select from databes and list them in a form which will return and update recodrs

Comment: if you put them all in one single textbox it will be very difficult to do the update afterwards, because you'll have one single variable coming back containing multiple values. Are you sure you don't want them to be in multiple textboxes, each name in a separate box? Then it's easy for the user to see, understand and edit, and easier for your code to process when it gets submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you end your while loop and you do

```
$names = implode(', ', $names);
```

After that you can put that string in your input like so:

```
<input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control" value="<?=$names ?>">
```

This put's a nice comma seperated list of all fetched names in your input field.

Comment: so is that right way I am coding ? and why use implode ?

Comment: implode turns your $names array into a string, so you can use it as a value in an input field

Comment: Tought I woudnt need to use implode with my array type ? I would need it if I was coding like $array= array("implode()","function","test","test1."); print_r($array);

Comment: Can you edit your post and put a clear text example of what exactly you wan't inside of your <input> value

Comment: you can use my answer to make those other input type have string values too. if it was helpfull to you please mark the answer

Comment: your answer is about usaq budd, (end part of the coding) I am asking how to do sql query with while loop ? and pass values to arrays and use them in a form in update item_page.php Which I am trying to do it up there with  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = ? AND user_id = ?";` prepared statments. not much helpfull thanks

Comment: You question: `My question is how to create array with while and use it in inputs ?` Is exactly answered with my answer, i don't know what more you do want....